# Can XSD extension re-order elements?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I want to extend a type in an XML Schema, say like this:

```
<complexType name="alienInfo">
  <complexContent>
    <extension base="personalInfo">
      <sequence>
        <element name="planet" type="xsd:string"/>
      </sequence>
    </extension>
  </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

where

```
<complexType name="personalInfo">
  <sequence>
    <element name="name" type="xsd:string" />
    <element name="age" type="xsd:int" />
  </sequence>
</complexType>
```

But I want to change the order of the constituent elements.   Say, have `planet` before `name` and `age`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Deriving Types by Extension](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#DerivExt) cannot be used to change the order of the elements in the base type:

> When a complex type is derived by extension, its effective content
>   model is the content model of the base type plus the content model
>   specified in the type derivation. Furthermore, the two content models
>   are treated as two children of a sequential group.

I have found that most concerns regarding element ordering -- allowing any order or changing an existing order -- are really unnecessary in the end.  I suggest that if extension works for you to achieve your goal, don't worry about changing the order of the elements in the base type.